# How to add n points between vertices when creating a polygon

Tags: java, math, polygon

Let's say I'm using the following code to create the vertices in a hexagon polygon:

```
hexagonPoints = new Array<Vector2>();
for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
{
  float x = r * (float)Math.cos(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f);
  float y = r * (float)Math.sin(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f);
  hexagonPoints.add(new Vector2(x, y));
}
```

How can I add additional points along each side of the polygon, so that there are n additional points between each connecting set of vertices? All vertices must be equal distance (including the vertices that formed the initial shape). E.g. before:

```
.   .

.   .
```

After (where n = 1):

```
. . .
.   .
. . .
```

**edit:** here's my current code based on Volker's suggestion:

```
float r = 3.0f;
int n = 1 + 2; // number of additional vertices between the main shape vertices
for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
{
    float xe = r * (float)Math.cos(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f);
    float ye = r * (float)Math.sin(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f);

    if (a > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            float xs = ((n - i) * hexagonPoints.get(a - 1).x + i * xe) / n;
            float ys = ((n - i) * hexagonPoints.get(a - 1).y + i * ye) / n;
            hexagonPoints.add(new Vector2(xs, ys));
        }
    }

    hexagonPoints.add(new Vector2(xe, ye));
}
```

This plots the additional vertices, but they are not in the correct positions.

**edit:** seems this wasn't working because I wasn't taking into account the first vertex position.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the endpoints of each side as you are doing it already. Then introduce with an inner loop the additional splitting points.

```
for (int i=1; i<n: ++i)
{
   float xs = ((n-i)*xb + i*xe)/n;
   float ys = ((n-i)*yb + i*ye)/n;
   hexagonPoints.add(new Vector(xs, ys));
}
hexagonPoints.add(new Vector(xe, ye));
```

where xb, yb is the beginning of a hexagon side and xe, ye the end.

Comment: Nice. @lepton note that the `n` in Volker's code should be equal to the number of segments needed between vertices, i.e. 1 + the number of extra points (think fences and fence posts)

Comment: Thanks guys. I added the inner loop as suggested by Volker (see edited OP), but the extra vertices are not being plotted in the correct position, they are being plotted inside the hexagon instead of between the main vertices. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: When you added xe,ye to hexagonPoints you have to switch to the beginning of the next line, i.e. x = xe; y= ye;

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution, based on Volker's suggestion:

```
int size = 6;
int npoints = 2;
int nsegs = npoints + 1;

float xb = r;
float yb = 0;
hexagonPoints.add(new Vector2(xb, yb));

for (int a = 1; a <= size; a++)
{
    float xe = r * (float) Math.cos(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f);
    float ye = r * (float) Math.sin(a * 60 * Math.PI / 180f);

    for (int i = 1; i < nsegs; ++i)
    {
        float xs = ((nsegs - i) * xb + i * xe) / nsegs;
        float ys = ((nsegs - i) * yb + i * ye) / nsegs;
        hexagonPoints.add(new Vector2(xs, ys));
    }

    if (a < size) hexagonPoints.add(new Vector2(xe, ye));
    xb = xe;
    yb = ye;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working now. Looks like mine wasn't working because I wasn't correctly setting the first start point. You need to change a < 6 to a < 7 in your code though for all six sides to be plotted.

Comment: You're welcome. a < 6 is correct, for a hexagon, since we're adding the first point (where a==0) before the start of the loop. Setting a < 7 will generate duplicate points.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were correct. I've edited the loop termination test to be `a <= size`. Now we also need to add a test to the addition of the end point. If `a == size` then we don't add it, as it'll be equal to the first point we added (unless you want to have first and last points equal).